# SQL Server sp_help : how to limit the number of output windows

Tags: sql-server-2008, sp-help-operator

Normally successful execution of

sp_help [*object_name*]

in SQL Server returns a total of 7 output windows with various results out of which normally I am interested in only 2 windows namely the one with all the column information and the one with the constraints.

Is there a way I can tell SQLserver to only display these while formulating the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't do this directly because the procedure is written to return that data, and TSQL has [no mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940/access-to-result-sets-from-within-stored-procedures-transact-sql-sql-server) for accessing specific result sets.

Long answer: but you can easily get the same information from other procedures or directly from the [system catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783(v=sql.100).aspx):

- `sp_columns`, `sp_helpconstraint` (this is actually called by `sp_help`) etc.
- `sys.columns`, `sys.objects` etc.

There's also the option of copying the source code from `sp_help` and using it as the basis of a new procedure that you create yourself, although personally I would just write it myself from scratch. If you do decide to write your own stored proc, you might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155378/reference-stored-procedures-for-all-databases-in-server) relevant too.